# How to test back end from front end?

Tags: testing, architecture, frontend, backend, performance-testing

Recently I've been asked this type of questions for several times.

It is like "If you can't access the back end, how do you know if a problem is from front end or back end?", or "If you can't access the database, how do you know the performance issue in the website is from the front end or back end?", or "In front end, how can you differentiate if a problem is from front end or from back end?"

I really don't have any clue how to answer this kind of questions. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be possible that they are asking this question only from  a system administrator perspective? So that frontend is the webserver and backend is the application server + db server?

Answer (score 0):

I think that alla the 4 questions could have a great number of answers,all of them depending from the context. Backend and frontend when using ajax requests get mixer a lot.

Let's say we're talking about performance problems in a website and we don't know anything about the architecture behind. 
In this case I would take a look into network stats and timelines from firebug or similar. If some sort of request to our application server is taking to much time it could be the backend. But how to be sure? maybe the frontend is asking with an ajax call for al the database entries while the pace only needs are to display just one entry. 
Maybe the only good answer for all the questions would be "I would start to look for performance bottlenecks and understand their nature "

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Our thoughts are quite similar. I did answered that ajax and firebug ways, but those people still gave me hints that there are some ways else.

Comment: If they give you the "right" answer I'll be curios to read it!